# tear drops disappearing during mirroring in altium

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, altium, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

I have recently faced a problem...whenever I mirror my pcb by using the shortcut>>M+i
all of the tear drops which are defined in my design will be disappeared! does anyone know why this problem happens??

thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the [altium discord site](https://discord.me/altium) - it's pretty active.

Answer (score 0):

Teardrops in Altium are not treated as primitives; instead they are a sort of post-processed element that's added on top and is never really merged with the routing. When you move a trace that has a teardrop on it, that element vanishes because the original location for it has changed. Not knowing how their code is written I don't know how else to describe it. At this point I don't really have a workaround, except to simply apply the teardrops at the very end of your routing process.

Comment: you really did me a favor